# Will post_exists work for draft posts?

Tags: posts, conditional-tags

Can i check if a post with the title "great title" exists even if this post status is set to "draft" with the function: `post_exists("great title")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as `post_exists("great title")` runs the following SQL:

```
SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE 1=1 AND post_title = 'great title'
```

so there's no *post status* or *post type* restriction.

Check the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/) on `post_exists()` for more info.

If you want to restrict by *post type*, you can use:

```
$found_page = get_page_by_title( "great title", $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' );
```

See the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/).

Comment: Thanks, i was actually looking at the docs and they don't seem to mention it (can you point me?). for some reason it doesn't seem to work for me, but now i will know to look for another reason...

Comment: You're welcome. I just looked at the code there :-)